# How to query MongoDB with deep and multiple levels

Tags: mongodb, notation, querying, levels

I have the following json as example:

```
{
"a": {
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d1": {
                "v1": "valv1",
                "v2": "valv2"
            },
            "d2": {
                "v1": "valv1",
                "v2": "valv2"
            },
            "d3": {
                "v1": "valv1",
                "v2": "valv2"
            },
            "d4": "vald4"
        },
        "c1": "vallc1"
    }
},
"a1": {
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d1": {
                "v1": "valv1",
                "v2": "valv2"
            },
            "d2": {
                "v1": "valv1",
                "v2": "valv2"
            },
            "d3": {
                "v1": "valv1",
                "v2": "valv2"
            },
            "d4": "vald4"
        },
        "c1": "vallc1"
    }
},
```

}

and I imported it in mongoDb.
Now, using "NoSQLBooster For MongoDb" I've tried to query the previous json to search something as "a.b.c.d1.v1" equals to "valv1" but when I'm building the query the NoSqlBooster shows me the following picture:

[image]

1. why the query builder stops at the third level?
2. how to search at a whatever level using dot notation?

Thanks in advance